# How to get Iphone ViewController sizes programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios

How to get and set iphone screen sizes and View sizes dynamically.. Suppose i'm setting imageview for an iphone, it should also fits to the ipad screen..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get the screen size, you can use

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
```

to get the size of your view, for example

```
UIViewController* myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
```

what you can do is similar to the one above

```
CGSize viewSize = myViewController.view.frame.size;
```

To set

```
myViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

Answer (score 1):

to set use

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

and to get

```
CGRect rect = view.frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `viewDidLoad` and write below code in the same.

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
```